# many DIV Containers in 2 columns with the same flexible height for each row

Tags: html, css

I solved The proble...The solution is here:http://jsfiddle.net/4Z8np/48/

---

I generated this HTML code by a PHP function:

```
<div class="columns">
<?php
foreach($rows as $rows))
{?>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $row->content ?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.columns{
 width:100%;
}

div.rows{
 width:50%;float:right;border:1px solid red
}
```

The structure is something like this:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="rows">
      <p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
      <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
      <p>text</p><p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
      <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Z8np/4

4/
The result is many red box in 2 colums beside each other...right?

**My Problem:**
The height of Red boxes are not same...and some times just one box is in a row.

**I Want to:**
I want to set each 2 Red box in each row with a same height.(according to bigger height not fix height)

How can do it?

---

EDITED:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Z8np/44/

This result is ugly...for example text7 has gone to a new line!

At least I wana text7 comes right after latest colums...

Comment: what's inside `$row->content`?

Comment: text,image...anything....But it's not fixed.

Comment: Can you provide a HTML output in a JS fiddle? It is difficult to guess what the php output is.

Comment: tnx for The answer...I added The code in JS fiddle

Comment: @user3362707 Why on Earth should he do that?

Comment: @user3362707 Having more specific rules is always good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using css display: (table|table-row|table-cell)?

http://jsfiddle.net/4Z8np/46/

```
div.table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div.row{
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
div.cell{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanls...I tired change your code for 2 colums but it has same problem